# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a JSF application that uses Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050, and I sometimes get the following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT XXXXX FROM XXXXX
bind => [/Home/Footer/]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="WWW.find" referenceClass=WWW sql="SELECT XXXXX FROM XXXXX")
```

I have no idea what is causing it. The exception is thrown in the following function on the "return q.getResultList();" line.

```
public List<WWW> find(String url) {
    }
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("WWW.find");
        q.setParameter("url", url);
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

---

We have SQL Server 2005 and the database isn't down. This is more of a recent thing to consistently happen. Below is the properties that we set in the persistence.xml file. Any comments on what should change in this?

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER:1433/DB"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.timeout" value="20"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.connections.wait-timeout" value="20"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="20"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

Here is my edited class
    public class WWWJpaController {

```
public WWWWJpaController() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("properties");
}

public WWWWJpaController(String unitName) {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(unitName);
}

private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public List<WWW> find(String url) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("WWW.find");
        q.setParameter("url", url);
        return q.getResultList();
    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Show your `getEntityManager()`. Btw: why don't you use `@PersistenceContext`? This way you never have to create/close it yourself.

Comment: Added my getEntityManager(). Do you have any links to examples using @PersistenceContext? I've never used that before.

Comment: @BalusC. I've just discovered that these problems occur when the backup of our server is done. We are running on a virtual server and when that server is backed up, it enters "save mode". Would this have any effect?

Comment: It's quite possible if this problem is just caused because the other end of the connection abruptly closed the connection while it's still in use. You'd need to investigate why that is happening during the backup. Is it restarting the server and/or its connection pool for some reason?

Comment: The error happened again over the weekend, when no backups were run. So I think it rules out the backups as the problems cause. Can you suggest some code that can check the connection prior to executing the select. And if the connection does not exist reconnect.

Comment: @BalusC. I put in some test code yesterday in the find method after the getEntityManager() line. I put the IF statement 'if (!em.isOpen())' and within that I put a log message. When the database  came to being in an invalid state and connection closed, I was expecting to see my log message. However I didn't. This indicates that the database connection is open. Am I wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your database connection has timed out, or your database is down.
You may need to retry the query, or re-connect your session.

How have you configured your connection pooling and what database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your aplication server is not able to reconnect to the database, as BalusC pointed out in his comment, this happens every time the backup's done.

You can make your server reconnect as pointed in [this link for Jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32023627/8084118)