# Azure SQL DB to SQL DW data loads through Talend is failing with java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: azure, talend

I am trying to load the data from Azure SQL DB to SQL DW through Talend Big Data Open Studio. I have altogether 25 tables that needs to be loaded and around 15 tables load is going fine and another 10 are failing with below error mesage. I am not very clear on what this means ? ( error details + snapshot of the error given below )

I tried recreating for the same tables thats failing and that continues to fail after recreation as well. Am I missing something ?

```
Exception in component tMSSqlInput_3
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.checkOpen(TdsCore.java:481)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.clearResponseQueue(TdsCore.java:767)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.reset(JtdsStatement.java:722)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.close(JtdsStatement.java:966)
at
```

Its  a simple one to one load from source to Target, no transformations involved.

I tried loading the same data through Powershell and that went fine.

[image: Snapshot of the error message displayed in Talend]

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845545/internal-exception-java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-state-the-connection-object): "My guess is your database connection has timed out, or your database is down." Do you use one connection? Or several? How big is the timeout for the source database? How long do the jobs run?

Comment: One connection is being used for all the loads and the same tables are failing every time( so I guess, it may not be a timeout related issue) and also I tried loading only that table - even that is failing..
 . Jobs are running for 2 to 3 minutes. Time out is set to 15 minutes...

Comment: Seems like a rights issue, a naming issue or the like to me when its not timeout related and your Powershell script runs through.

Comment: Getting this issue intermittently on a cloud hosted server as well. I am using SQL 2008 R2 and it works perfectly for weeks then it just fails and I cant get it running. Using servicemix instead of talend. Did you ever find anything to help?